# Memory Usage with UICollectionView extremely high

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am having an issue with memory usage. Whenever I scroll or reload the data the memory usage keeps going up and never goes down. I have a feeling that for some reason the cells are not releasing any of the items displayed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am quite sure I am doing something wrong, but I can't seem to find what.

Thank you in advance

Here is the code for creating my UICollectionView:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Crashlytics

public class podCollectionView : UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate  {
private var collectionView : UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())   // Initialization
private var inmates : NSArray = [];
private var context : NSManagedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext;
private var configuration = Configuration.sharedInstance;
private var titleView = UILabel();
private var database : FMDatabase = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).database!;


public override func viewDidLoad() {
    getInmates();
    super.viewDidLoad();
    self.collectionView = podMainView(x: "1", y: "2");
    self.collectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CellCell") // UICollectionViewCell
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor();
    self.collectionView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.collectionView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    self.collectionView.delegate = self     // delegate  :  UICollectionViewDelegate
    self.collectionView.dataSource = self   // datasource  : UICollectionViewDataSource

    self.view.addSubview(self.collectionView);

    self.view = self.collectionView;
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:false);

    var inmateRefresh: NSTimer!
    gameTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(120, target: self, selector: #selector(refreshDAta), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);



}

public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return self.inmates.count;
}

public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let retVal : UICollectionViewCell = self.collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellCell", forIndexPath: indexPath);
    retVal.prepareForReuse();
    retVal.addSubview(InmateSummary(inmate: self.inmates.objectAtIndex(indexPath.item) as! NSArray,parent: self));
    return retVal;
}


private func getInmates(){
    var totalInmates = 0;
    var inmatesInArea = 0;
    var inmatesOutOfArea = 0;
    self.inmates = [];
    do{
        let tmpInmates : NSMutableArray = [];
        let rs = try self.database.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM inmates WHERE podName='"+self.configuration.currentArea+"' ORDER BY suicideBlue DESC", values: nil)
        while rs.next() {
             let rowData : NSMutableArray = []
            let colCount = Int(rs.columnCount()) as Int;
            for i in 0 ..< colCount {
                rowData.addObject(rs.objectForColumnName(rs.columnNameForIndex(Int32(i))));
            }


            if rowData[7] as! String == "" {
                inmatesInArea = inmatesInArea + 1;
            }else{
                inmatesOutOfArea = inmatesOutOfArea + 1;
            }
            totalInmates = totalInmates + 1;
            tmpInmates.addObject(rowData);
        }

        self.inmates = tmpInmates;


    } catch {
        CLSLogv("Error while loading inmates in main screen \(error)%@", getVaList(["three"]));
    }

    let barText = String(inmatesInArea) + "/" + String(inmatesOutOfArea) + " (" + String(totalInmates) + ")";

    let buttonBack: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom) as UIButton
    buttonBack.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 40)
    buttonBack.setTitle(barText, forState: .Normal);

    let leftBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: buttonBack)

    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(leftBarButtonItem, animated: false)
    //self.database.close();
}

public func changePod(pod:String){
    self.configuration.currentArea = pod;
    self.titleView.text = pod + " ▼";
    self.getInmates();
    self.collectionView.reloadData();
}

public func refreshDAta(){
    self.database.close();
    self.database.open();

        let inmateFetcer = InmateFetcher();
        inmateFetcer.getUpdates();


        self.getInmates();
        //self.inmates = [];
        self.collectionView.reloadData();

        NSLog("DATA REFRESHED");


}

override public func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}
}
```

And here is the code for the views within the cells:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit


public class InmateSummary : UIView, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate{
public var inmate:NSArray;
private var screenSize : CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds;
private var configuration = Configuration.sharedInstance;
private var parent : podCollectionView;

init(inmate:NSArray, parent:podCollectionView){
    let cellHeight = screenSize.height * 0.295;
    let cellWidth = screenSize.width * 0.295;
    self.inmate = inmate;
    self.parent = parent;
    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight));

    let aSelector : Selector = #selector(InmateSummary.inmateClicked(_:));
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector);
    tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1);

    let topView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight*0.10));
    topView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor();

    self.addSubview(topView);

    let cellLab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight*0.10));
    cellLab.text = self.inmate[3] as? String;
    cellLab.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    cellLab.font = UIFont.init(name:"Arial-BoldMT", size: 30);
    cellLab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;

    self.addSubview(cellLab);

    let sexLab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cellWidth*0.75, y: 0, width: cellWidth*0.25, height: cellHeight*0.10));
    sexLab.text = self.inmate[1] as? String
    sexLab.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    sexLab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;

    self.addSubview(sexLab);

    let greyView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cellHeight*0.10, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight*0.70));
    greyView.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor();

    self.addSubview(greyView);

    if self.inmate[7] as? String == "" {
        greyView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
    }



    let eventLab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cellWidth*0.75, y: 0, width: cellWidth*0.25, height: cellHeight*0.10));
    eventLab.text = self.inmate[7] as? String;
    eventLab.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    eventLab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    eventLab.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;

    greyView.addSubview(eventLab);


    let classLab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellWidth*0.25, height: cellHeight*0.10));
    classLab.text = self.inmate[4] as? String;
    classLab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    classLab.font = UIFont.init(name:"Arial-BoldMT", size: 20);
    classLab.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;

    if(classLab.text == "RISK"){
        classLab.textColor = UIColor.yellowColor();
    }else if(classLab.text == "7CLS"){
        classLab.textColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green:0.5, blue:0.0, alpha:1);
    }else if(classLab.text == "8MAX"){
        classLab.textColor = UIColor(red:1.0, green:0.0, blue:0.0, alpha:0.7);
    }else{
        classLab.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    }

    greyView.addSubview(classLab);
    var mugshot : UIImage = UIImage();
    if (self.inmate[12] as? NSData) != nil {
        mugshot = UIImage(data: (self.inmate[12] as? NSData)!)!;
    }else{
        NSLog("Inmate without mugshot: %@",self.inmate[2] as! String);
    }
    let mugshotView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: cellWidth*0.16, y: cellHeight*0.09, width: cellWidth*0.66, height: cellHeight*0.5));
    mugshotView.image = mugshot;

    greyView.addSubview(mugshotView);

    let bookingNumber = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cellWidth*0.25, y: cellHeight*0.545, width: cellWidth*0.50, height: cellHeight*0.15));
    bookingNumber.text = self.inmate[2] as? String;
    bookingNumber.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    bookingNumber.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    bookingNumber.font = UIFont.init(name:"Arial-BoldMT", size: 20);
    bookingNumber.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;

    greyView.addSubview(bookingNumber);

    let nameView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cellHeight*0.75, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight*0.25));


    self.addSubview(nameView);

    let maxRed = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cellWidth*0.33, height: cellHeight*0.115));
    maxRed.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
    if (self.inmate[15] as! NSNumber == 1) {
        maxRed.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
    }
    nameView.addSubview(maxRed);

    let suBlue = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: cellWidth*0.33, y: 0, width: cellWidth*0.33, height: cellHeight*0.115));
    suBlue.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
    if (self.inmate[18] as! NSNumber  == 1) {
        let aSelector : Selector = #selector(InmateSummary.suicideClicked(_:));
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector);
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        nameView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);
        suBlue.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor();
    }
    nameView.addSubview(suBlue);
    let segGreen = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: cellWidth*0.66, y: 0, width: cellWidth*0.33, height: cellHeight*0.115));
    segGreen.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
    if (self.inmate[5] as! NSNumber == 1) {
        segGreen.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor();
    }
    nameView.addSubview(segGreen);



    let nameLab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cellWidth*0.025, y: cellHeight*0.12, width: cellWidth*0.95, height: cellHeight*0.05));
    nameLab.text = self.inmate[0] as? String;
    nameLab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
    nameLab.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
    nameLab.font = UIFont.init(name:"Arial-BoldMT", size: 20);
    nameLab.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
    nameView.addSubview(nameLab);

    if(self.inmate[18] as! NSNumber == 1){
        //NSLog("Suicide: %@",self.inmate);
        let checkLab = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: cellHeight*0.17, width: cellWidth, height: cellHeight*0.07));

        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd HH:mm"
        let tmpDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: (self.inmate[19] as! NSString).doubleValue)
        let dateString = formatter.stringFromDate(tmpDate);

        checkLab.text = (self.inmate[22] as? String)! + " - " + dateString;
        checkLab.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center;
        checkLab.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor();
        checkLab.font = UIFont.init(name:"Arial", size: 18);
        checkLab.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
        nameView.addSubview(checkLab);
    }

    if self.inmate[1] as? String == "F" {
        nameView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor();
    }

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true;

}
func suicideClicked(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer!){
    let podsChooser = ActivityChooser(parentView:self);

    podsChooser.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover;

    let popoverMenuViewController = podsChooser.popoverPresentationController

    popoverMenuViewController!.permittedArrowDirections = .Any
    popoverMenuViewController!.delegate = self
    popoverMenuViewController!.sourceView = sender.view;
    self.parent.presentViewController(
        podsChooser,
        animated: true,
        completion: nil)
}

func inmateClicked (sender:InmateSummary){
    NSLog("Inmate Clicked");

    let vc = SingleInmateDisplay(inmate: inmate);
    self.parent.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc,animated:false);
}

required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Comment: You cannot give us a couple hundred of lines and expect us to go through them and find your memory leak.
Try googling how to find memory leaks and narrow your problem. If you do that and you haven't found a solution, create a new question with all the information you've gathered, THEN we can help you.

Comment: Are you testing it on simulator or on actual device?
If you are doing this test in simulator than I would suggest to use actual device. You might get different result

Comment: This is on an actual device (iPad Mini Model:MK6J2LL/A)

Comment: Are you having lot's of images in you UICollectionView? There are different methods for storing/read images/data in-memory/storage that will make less impact on the memory.

Comment: Your code is odd. Just off the top of my head: `1)` In `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` you call `prepareForReuse` - but why when this is done automatically? `2` In `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` you constantly add new sub views to `dequeue`ed cells but do not have any code to remove the subviews (this alone will cause your memory to constantly increase) `3)` in `viewDidLoad` you add your Collection View as a `subView` of `self.view` but then immediately on the next line you set your `self.view` to be your Collection View. My advice - use Storyboards and design your UI there.

Comment: Robotic Cat, #1 was taken from googling the problem, so I can remove that, it did break things so I left it. I think #2 is the issue, any advice or pointers to articles that explain how to clean up those views?